# How to compare to System.Type?

Tags: c#, types

In `DataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0]` we have a `DataType` property. Now, I would like to iterate over `Columns` and perform some action depending on the `Type` in `DataType`. How to do this?

```
foreach(var c in DataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
{
  if (c.DataType == System.String) {} //error 'string' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator:

```
if (c.DataType == typeof(string))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Marc: That's not the same thing. `c.DataType` is a `Type`, not a `string`. Your code will always evaluate to false.

Comment: I was wondering what I was missing, thanks! I put that comment hoping that it would be rebuked or confirmed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
if (c.DataType == typeof(string)) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (c.DataType == typeof(string))
{
    // code
}
```